# Javafx transition animation

Tags: animation, javafx-2, java-8

I'm trying javafx's transition animations examples, and I noticed that there is no way to get the moved object x/y coordinates after the end of animation.

```
public class ArcToDemo extends Application {

    private PathTransition pathTransitionCircle;

    private void init(Stage primaryStage) {
        Group root = new Group();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 600, 460));

        // Cirle path example

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 20, 20);
        rect.setArcHeight(10);
        rect.setArcWidth(10);
        rect.setFill(Color.GREEN);
        root.getChildren().add(rect);

        Path path = createEllipsePath(400, 200, 150, 150, 0);
        root.getChildren().add(path);

        Button btn1 = new Button();
        btn1.setText("btn1");
        btn1.relocate(100, 0);
        btn1.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if(pathTransitionCircle.statusProperty().get() == Animation.Status.STOPPED)
                    pathTransitionCircle.play();
                else
                    pathTransitionCircle.stop();
                System.out.println(rect.getX());
            }
        });
        root.getChildren().add(btn1);

        pathTransitionCircle = new PathTransition();
        pathTransitionCircle.setDuration(Duration.millis(2000));
        pathTransitionCircle.setPath(path);
        pathTransitionCircle.setNode(rect);
        pathTransitionCircle.setOrientation(PathTransition.OrientationType.ORTHOGONAL_TO_TANGENT);
        pathTransitionCircle.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
        pathTransitionCircle.setAutoReverse(false);
    }

    private Path createEllipsePath(double centerX, double centerY, double radiusX, double radiusY, double rotate) {
        ArcTo arcTo = new ArcTo();
        arcTo.setX(centerX - radiusX + 1); // to simulate a full 360 degree celcius circle.
        arcTo.setY(centerY - radiusY);
        arcTo.setSweepFlag(false);
        arcTo.setLargeArcFlag(true);
        arcTo.setRadiusX(radiusX);
        arcTo.setRadiusY(radiusY);
        arcTo.setXAxisRotation(rotate);

        Path path = new Path();
        path.getElements().add(new MoveTo(centerX - radiusX, centerY - radiusY));
        path.getElements().add(arcTo);
        path.getElements().add(new ClosePath());
        path.setStroke(Color.DODGERBLUE);
        path.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(5d, 5d);
        return path;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        init(primaryStage);
        primaryStage.show();
        pathTransitionCircle.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

rect.getX() or rect.getLayoutX() return 0 like the element is not moved at all. Is that what the animation does? Is there atleast a way to get the coordinates from the animation and set them to the rectangle using relocate(x, y) ?

............................................EDIT.....................................................

translateX/Y works just need to add the new circle's radius to match

```
pathTransitionCircle.stop();
Path path2 = createEllipsePath((int)rect.translateXProperty().get() + 50,(int)rect.translateYProperty().get() + 50, 50, 50, 0);
root.getChildren().add(path2);
pathTransitionCircle.setPath(path2);
pathTransitionCircle.play();
```

Thank you @James_D and @Nikos Paraskevopoulos, this solution will work for me.

Comment: The `PathTransition` updates the `translateX` and `translateY` properties of the node (from the Javadocs). Check those out.

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos thank you. The translateX/Y seems to work fine, but when I try setting the coordinates
rect.setLayoutX((int)rect.translateXProperty().get());
rect.setLayoutY((int)rect.translateYProperty().get());
it goes bad : 
http://puu.sh/cUtpX/e9d8621bae.png
http://puu.sh/cUtv8/5d23781889.png

Comment: I guess setting the coordinates applies the transformation twice. Why do you need to set them? Can't you work with the transform?

Comment: @Nikos Paraskevopoulos I want to initiate a new animation after this one has finished with the same object. Maybe I should consider deleting this one, creating a new with the coordinates from translateX/Y and use it instead if this is the only solution.

Comment: Just start the new animation using the `translateX` and `translateY` properties. It's hard to see what the issue is: the only code you have posted is code that does what it's supposed to do. Perhaps you should post the code where you create the new animation and explain the difference between the behavior you want and the behavior you get.